# How to change the background color of an ion-list

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm unable to change the color of an ion-list of a chat app I've created.

I've seen several answers to my questions regarding this issue, but none have worked for me.

Here's what I've tried:
.item .item-content {
background-color: transparent !important;
}

That did not work.

Here's the html and css

```css
.message{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.other-user{
    background: #92B399;
    color: white;
}

.me{
    background: #9FBADF;
    color: white;
}

.time{
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: small;
}

.message-input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid var(--ion-color-medium);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white;
    resize: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #000;
}

ion-item {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Chat</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content #content>
  <ion-list lines="none" *ngIf="messages.length > 0">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages; index as i; trackBy: trackByCreated">
      <div size="9" *ngIf="msg.sendingUserId !== auth.currentUser.uid" class="message other-user">
        <span>{{msg.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
          {{msg.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
      </div>
      <div offset="3" size="9" *ngIf="msg.sendingUserId === auth.currentUser.uid" class="message me" slot="end">
        <span>{{msg.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
          {{msg.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-row align-items-center no-padding>
      <ion-col size="10">
        <textarea autosize maxRows="3" [(ngModel)]="newMsg" class="message-input"></textarea>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="2">
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" color="primary" [disabled]="newMsg === ''" class="msg-btn"
          (click)="sendMessage()">
          <ion-icon name="send-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I'm wondering if there's some sort of shadow dom element I can't see.  Here's what I see on inspection:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciate.  I've tried changing the background-color in the css to no avail.  Also tried !important

Answer (score 1):

I had to change a default setting of --ion-item-background: white;
the variables.scss.  It defaulted black.